# Any obvious flaws in this protocol?

Tags: protocols, key-exchange

Are there any particular flaws in this protocol?

(Yes I know about SSL)

Three participants:

Login Server **LS**
Game Server **GS**
Client **C**

Asymmetric key-pair **Kpriv Kpub**
Shared 128bit secret key **Ksec**
Shared 128bit signing key **Ksecsign**
Client secret **Csec**
Login Server nonce **NonceLS**
Client Login nonce **NonceC**
Game Server nonce **NonceGS**

Session **S**

**Before start**

**LS** holds *Kpriv*, *Ksec* and Ksecsign
**GS** hold *Ksec*, Ksecsign
**C** holds **Kpub**

All symmetric encryption uses AES-128, asymmetric uses 2048 bit RSA. HMAC uses SHA-256. PBKDF2 uses HMAC SHA-256.

1. **C** connects to **LS**.
2. **C** sends a *puzzle request*.
3. **LS** responds with a *puzzle challenge* which is a unique random nonce and a difficulty.
4. **C** computes a puzzle reply and creates a random nonce **Csec**
5. **C** encrypts nonce + client information (type of device etc) using **Kpub**.
6. **C** Sends a *session request* with the puzzle reply in the clear, and the rest of the data encrypted (as detailed in 5). I.e. puzzle-reply || EKpub(Csec || device data)
7. **LS** queues **C**'s request according to the quality of the puzzle reply. If the queue is full and **C**'s puzzle answer isn't better than the worst reply in the queue, it replies with a *request failed*. **C** can then start from (2)
8. **LS** decrypts the payload. It then creates **NonceLS** and creates two keys using PBKDF2 with HmacSHA256 from (**NonceLS** || **Csec**) and two different salts.
9. **LS** then encrypts (**Csec** || device data || **NonceLS**) using **Ksec** and signs this with a HMAC using **Ksecsign**. This is the new session. (S <- HMACKsecsign(IV || EKsec(...)) || EKsec(**Csec** || device data || **NonceLS** || timestamp) || IV).
10. **LS** Then uses the same method (encrypt-then-sign) as above with the derived keys in (8) to create encrypted data to give to the client. I.e. the client receives **NonceLS** || HMAC(IV || E(**S**)) || E(**S**) || IV.
11. **C** Construct the same keys as in (8) and use them to verify, then decrypt the message. **C** now has **NonceLS**, **S** and **Csec**.
12. **C** connects to **GS**
13. **C** creates a new nonce **NonceC** and sends **NonceC** || **S** *in the clear* to **GS**
14. **GS** decrypts and verifies **S** using the shared **Ksec** and **Ksecsign**. It logs the device information (note that forged device information isn't a problem) and creates a new nonce **NonceGS**. It then generates a key and sign key using different salts with PBKDF2 and **NonceC** || **NonceLS** || **NonceGS** || **Csec**. (If the session is expired, then an error code is returned, which requires **C** to request a new **S** from the **LS**)
15. **GS** Then replies in the clear with (1 byte result || **NonceGS**)
16. **C** Sets up the same key as **GS** and start sending packets in the following format: (2-byte packet length || HMAC(IV || E(...)) || E(packet number || data) || IV). Packet numbers start at 0 and are increased by 1 for each packet sent. HMAC is first verified, then decryption is done, followed by packet number verification.

For both server and client decryption, if there is any packet integrity error anywhere, the server/client disconnects. In order to reconnect a new handshake is required, which will mean a new **NonceC** and new **NonceGS**.

There are some omissions in this protocol as far as I can tell, which I don't know how they will affect the general security of the protocol:

1. There is no signing in (6)
2. Packet length can be tampered with.
3. (10) **NonceLS** is not included in the HMAC (I will fix this)

I'm also considering switching to - for example - AES in CTR mode for (16) to avoid the IV / packet number / padding overheads for each packet.

EDIT:

I try to assure the following:

1. Only a server holding **Kpriv** can issue a valid session **S** to a client.
2. No one but the holders of **Ksec** can decrypt a session **S**.
3. The session **S** is resistant to tampering.
4. A holder of a session **S** and the secret key **Csec** can initiate use these to initiate a confidential connection with a server holding **Ksec**
5. Encrypted sessions in (4) is not vulnerable to man-in-the-middle, replay or other attacks.
6. A large amount of session requests (1) cannot CPU-exchaust a server.
7. Initiating a encrypted session (4) is inexpensive CPU-wise.
8. Session requests and replies are not vulnerable to attacks such as replay or man-in-the-middle.

EDIT 2:

To clarify, this is TCP all the way.

EDIT 3:

The key exchange works like this:

Client **A**, Login Server **S**, Game Server **B**

(1) A → S : { N<sub>a</sub>, A }<sub>K<sub>pub</sub></sub>

K<sub>sa</sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sub>s</sub>, A, Salt<sub>enc</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

K<sub>sa<sub>sign</sub></sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sub>s</sub>, A, Salt<sub>sign</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

M ← IV || HMAC(IV, { N<sub>a</sub>, A }<sub>K<sub>sb</sub></sub>)<sub>K<sub>sb<sub>sign</sub></sub></sub> || { N<sub>a</sub>, A }<sub>K<sub>sb</sub></sub>

(2) S ➝ A : { N<sub>s</sub>, IV, HMAC(IV, { N<sub>s</sub>, M }<sub>K<sub>sa</sub></sub>)<sub>K<sub>sa<sub>sign</sub></sub></sub>, { N<sub>s</sub>, M }<sub>K<sub>sa</sub></sub> }

(3) A ➝ B : { N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub>, M }

(4) B ➝ A : { N<sub>b</sub> }

K<sub>ab</sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub> N<sub>b</sub>, Salt<sub>enc</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

K<sub>ab<sub>sign</sub></sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub> N<sub>b</sub>, Salt<sub>sign</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

Encryption proceeds using K<sub>ab</sub>, signing each with K<sub>ab<sub>sign</sub></sub> and keeping a running counter with each packet.

There are some weaknesses in this as written.

If you have a well-tested *strong* key exchange protocol I could use as a drop-in replacement that would be fine.

The requirements are:

1. No communication between S and B.
2. S and B can share a finite limits of secrets before all exchanges.
3. A possess a public key and S holds the private counterpart.
4. A-B key negotiation should not use asymmetric key exchange.

Comment: What are you trying to ensure with your protocol?  Without that information, there can be no flaws.

Comment: @Ladadadada updated the question.

Comment: My initial reaction is that this protocol is inefficient,  but that is a more difficult problem to fix.  Are you using AES in CTR mode or another mode?  You should have committed to a mode of operation before talking about the protocol.  You need integrity checking on every encrypted request (or you could construct a cryptography oracle...), step 6 can be signed with kpub.  Also what is the "*puzzle*"?

Comment: @Rook inefficient in what sense? I was originally simply running AES CBC, which I believe should be ok against attacks as long as the HMAC check is correct.  The puzzle is just find a value n such that SHA1(challenge nonce | n) has at least <difficulty> number of trailing zeroes. Integrity checks are everywhere except for the initial public key. I'll add it, but is there really room for an exploit here? Is it really helpful to alter the public key-signed request?

Comment: @Nuoji well first off,  using key stretching with PBKDF2 in an HMAC with a secret as a derived key?  The threat of DoS is is greater than the threat posed by brute forcing such a massive keyspace in a short lived session.  What advantage does this HMAC have over an authenticated mode like GCM or CCM? Authenticated modes lend them selves to beatiful designs.  In terms of the second question: at no point should you ever have secret transmitted over an insecure channel without verifying that this secret wasn't modified.  Padding oracles and decryption oracles affect AES-CBC. But still a concern.

Comment: Is this UDP or TCP?

Comment: @tylerl it's TCP all the way.

Comment: @Rook I'm uncertain of what you mean. PBKDF2 is used to create new sign / encryption keys for each connection (from NonceC || NonceLS || NonceGS || Csec where NonceC and NonceGS are unique for each connection) salting PBKDF2 with different salts for sign and encryption.

Comment: @Rook the advantage I've had with AES-CBC + HMAC-SHA256 is the ready availability of these cryptographic primitives in well-used libraries, letting me not worry so much about the actual implementation of them and focusing on the higher level aspects of the protocol. In order to use CCM or GCM I feel I must thoroughly understand them first. I've started to ask a bit about perhaps switching to CTR or some variant thereof, for example here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/recommended-authenticated-stream-cipher-for-minimum-overhead

Comment: You might want to consider the five principles from http://www.auug.org.au/resources/proceedings/auug2004/li.pdf

Answer (score 5):

**Note: according to comments, this protocol doesn't use UDP. But i'll leave the answer here as it might be useful to someone else.**

From your language it sounds like you're using UDP instead of TCP. Perhaps you're not, but you didn't specify. And if you are, then here's something to think about.

This is especially significant if the packet boundaries are not random and unpredictable.

If you're ignoring dropped packets (as almost all UDP apps do), see the paragraph below. If you aren't, then you'll have to think about retransmission (and when and how to trigger it), out-of-order arrival, sliding window oriented reassembly, window size and expansion, and path MTU and MTU discovery... and/or fragmentation. I guess that applies even if you don't discard packets. This can really affect network throughput, especially given the fact that arrival order is significant from a security standpoint. In other words, if you're not ignoring dropped packets, the consider TCP instead.

But if you *do* discard dropped packets, then the size of the packets (or timing, or other similar metadata) may be indicative of the action that the packet represents. That's an information disclosure vulnerability already (exploitable? depends on context). But if a MITM could selectively discard or otherwise affect packets based on their function, that could trigger a false assumption in the client or server. Perhaps a transaction is confirmed only to one party, perhaps certain actions or commands can be filtered, perhaps some security-related function can be suppressed.

Again, it all depends on context. Which I guess is just another way of saying that there's not enough information to evaluate this properly.