# Is there a known vetted alternative to this key-exchange protocol?

Tags: protocols, key-exchange

I have three participants:

1. A client **A** in possession of the public key K<sub>pub</sub>
2. A login server **S** in possession of the private key K<sub>priv</sub>
3. Game servers **B** (B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub> etc)
4. **S** and all **B** may share a finite number of secrets before, but not after the exchange. This is basically a scalability measure. If **S** would need to send data to **B** in order to create a key for **A**, then that makes scalability harder.
5. **A** and **B** should not use asymmetric key exchange, to reduce CPU impact on game servers.

The current scheme works roughly like this:

Client **A**, Login Server **S**, Game Server **B**

(1) A → S : { N<sub>a</sub>, A }<sub>K<sub>pub</sub></sub>

K<sub>sa</sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sub>s</sub>, A, Salt<sub>enc</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

K<sub>sa<sub>sign</sub></sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sub>s</sub>, A, Salt<sub>sign</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

M ← IV || HMAC(IV, { N<sub>a</sub>, A, T<sub>timestamp</sub> }<sub>K<sub>sb</sub></sub>)<sub>K<sub>sb<sub>sign</sub></sub></sub> || { N<sub>a</sub>, A, T<sub>timestamp</sub> }<sub>K<sub>sb</sub></sub>

(2) S ➝ A : { N<sub>s</sub>, IV, HMAC(IV, { N<sub>s</sub>, M }<sub>K<sub>sa</sub></sub>)<sub>K<sub>sa<sub>sign</sub></sub></sub>, { N<sub>s</sub>, M }<sub>K<sub>sa</sub></sub> }

(3) A ➝ B : { N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub>, M }

(4) B ➝ A : { N<sub>b</sub> }

K<sub>ab</sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub> N<sub>b</sub>, Salt<sub>enc</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

K<sub>ab<sub>sign</sub></sub> ← { N<sub>a</sub>, N<sup>'</sup><sub>a</sub> N<sub>b</sub>, Salt<sub>sign</sub> }<sub>PBKDF2</sub>

Encryption proceeds using K<sub>ab</sub>, signing each with K<sub>ab<sub>sign</sub></sub> and keeping a running counter with each packet.

I'm aware of some weaknesses in this as it is written which I intend to fix, but you should get the general idea of what I'm doing:

1. Client **A** requests an encrypted packet containing it's nonce N<sub>a</sub> securely from **S**.
2. **S** returns the packet encrypted packet in a way that **A** can assure the packet is from **S**.
3. Client **A** gives the packet in the clear to **B** (since no one but **B** or **S** can decrypt it), who unpacks the nonce and can create a shared key K<sub>ab</sub>. This shared key is then used for the remaining communication, such as authenticating or registering **A**. (Of course, there are nonces thrown in, so each new request for a K<sub>ab</sub> will produce new keys)

So this is basically just for ensuring confidentiality of the channel between **A** and **B**.

The nice thing is that if the connection is dropped or logged out, then **A** can  use M again for new connections to **B** without keys being repeated.

Now, given the difficulty getting a protocol right, it would be awesome to use a well-known vetted protocol for this.

Does anyone know of an alternative that works in a similar manner that I could replace it with?

EDIT:

The aim here is exchange keys in order to set up a secure channel between **A** and **B**. This is because at this point **A** might not be registered at **B**, so will need a way to register securely without anyone eavesdropping on that registration.

This is why the Kerberos model doesn't work - **A** might be entirely unknown to **S** and **B**.

I'm seeing the following possible threats I want to avoid:

1. Someone eavesdrops on **A**'s registration and is then able to login as **A**.
2. Someone eavesdrops on **A**'s login and is then able to play as **A**.
3. Someone eavesdrops on **A**'s login and is able to login as **A** by replaying the first messages. This will cause **A** to get disconnected even if the attacker can't continue the conversation.
4. If, due to network issues, many clients simultaneously disconnect and then reconnect, the reconnect is sufficiently costly that **B** is unable to process all connects.
5. Someone mounts a man-in-the-middle attack and is able to randomly change what **A** does.
6. Someone redirects traffic to a server **B'** without **A** being aware of it.
7. A DDoS acting like (4) should only affect the server attacked.

Or more succinctly:

- **A** can safely play - any covert manipulation will be detected by client and/or server and no-one can steal **A**'s credentials without accessing the data in the client directly.
- The server topology is not sensitive to DoS / DDoS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by (rephrasing): _"... if the connection is dropped or logged out, client can request new secure session while it's still valid"_. I think there's a problem right there, no? Could you also share with us reasons for dropping your [previously suggested protocol](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/37592/20074)? It might help finding an answer. ;)

Comment: @TildalWave basically the "session" M contains a nonce only known to the client and anyone who can decrypt M. Using this secret nonce together with public nonces from A and B, we can create new keys without having to retrieve a new session every time. Since public nonces from A and B are new for every connect, we can assure ourselves that our keys are different for each connect, even if the "session" used is the same.

Comment: @TildalWave the "previously suggested protocol" is exactly what I detail above. So basically this is asking if there's an alternative to my own hand-rolled protocol.

Comment: Who calculates K(ab) ? A and B? If so how do they get the same Salt(enc) value?

Comment: @jcopenha A and B both do. Salts are constants and are only used to make sure keys for encryption and signing are different.

Comment: 1) Sounds somewhat similar to kerberos. 2) I think you're overestimating the cost of asymmetric crypto. You can easily do several thousand key-exchanges per second.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I already tried a protocol with asymmetric key exchange. Granted, I used too large a key (which upped the cost by a magnitude), but even with that taken into a account I saw a large CPU impact so early that it's not an attractive solution. Also, with a separate login server, I can assure that resource-exhausting DoS/DDoS attack on the login won't affect games running on a different machine.

Comment: @CodesInChaos as for Kerberos, the similarity is in the encrypted session data M. Unlike Kerberos there is no central key store, instead I rely on an asymmetric key to securely request a "ticket". This in turn makes quite a different set of possible issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what your requirements are -- strangely, you don't seem to have listed the security requirements, or threat model, or what you are trying to achieve -- but the obvious approach would be to use a [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29)-like (Needham-Schroeder-style) protocol. Those schemes give S a way to help A and B establish a secure channel between them. They can be implemented using just symmetric-key cryptography, so they should perform and scale extremely well.

In straightforward [Needham-Schroeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol), we assume that initially S and A share a symmetric key (K<sub>S,A</sub>) known only to them, and that S and B share a symmetric key (K<sub>S,B</sub>) known only to them. After execution of the protocol, A and B receive a session key (K<sub>A,B</sub>) that's known only to them, and that A and B can use to communicate securely (to establish a secure channel between them). Both A and B receive assurances of each other's identity. The Needham-Schroeder protocol has been well-studied; for instance, early versions had a subtle flaw, which was subsequently [discovered and corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol#Fixing_the_man-in-the-middle_attack) in later research by Gavin Lowe.

If there is some reason why the server needs to authenticate itself using public-key cryptography, Needham-Schroeder can probably be modified in a straightforward way to support that. (For instance, A could connect to S using TLS or something similar; then S could continue from there to help A and B establish a secure session key K<sub>A,B</sub>, by sending K<sub>A,B</sub> to A, and also giving A an encrypted version of the session key, encrypted in such a way that B can decrypt it and verify its freshness.)

Comment: Actually I think you identified it. The first part of my protocol is very similar to TLS (with the client already holding the server cert, and the second part to Needham-Schroeder. But surely someone must have married those two before?